# google search box is not displayed on IE 9

Tags: google-search

I embedded Google search engine to my website. It work properly on firefox and chrome but not on IE 9. It does not provide a search box as usual.

Please guide me how to solve this problem. thankx.
the block code is below:

```
<div class="searchbox">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            (function () {
                var cx = '014563576809462078162:fo8kwqn2rea';
                var gcse = document.createElement('script');
                gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
                gcse.async = true;
                gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                    '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
                // document.body.appendChild(gcse);
                document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(gcse);
            })();
        });

    </script>
    <gcse:searchbox></gcse:searchbox>
</div>
<div class="resultBox">
    <gcse:searchresults></gcse:searchresults>
</div>
```

Comment: which IE version you are using??

Comment: i captured from "About Internet Explorer": version: 9.0.8112.16421. Update version 9.0.30